# jQuery select inside popup not working with Android

Tags: jquery, select, mobile, popup

Here is my problem.

I place a select tag (dynamically) into a jQuery popup that is working fine on every platform browsers except my Samsung Galaxy S1 whatever the browser is.
The select won't drop down. If i try to set it native without using jQuery the problem remains the same.

Adding this select tag outside of popup will work fine on my SGS 1.
What could be wrong with my code ?

Here is an sample of the code involved :

**HTML**

```
        <div data-role="popup" id="popABS" data-theme="c">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                <h1></h1>
            </div>
            <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Fermer</a>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-content-theme="b">
                    <div id="detABS" data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-icon="arrow" data-content-theme="b">
                        <h2>Détail des absences</h2>
                        <table id="table-ABS" class="ui-responsive table-stroke" data-role="table" data-mode="reflow">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                    <th>Code</th>
                                    <th>Libellé</th>
                                    <th>Début</th>
                                    <th>Fin</th>
                                    <th>Niveau</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div id="ajABS" data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b" style="display:none;">
                        <h2>Demande d'absence</h2>
                        <fieldset id="jouh" data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" data-type="horizontal">
                            <input type="radio" name="typabs" id="typabs-j" value="J" checked="checked" />
                            <label for="typabs-j">Jour</label>

                            <input type="radio" name="typabs" id="typabs-h" value="H"  />
                            <label for="typabs-h">Heures</label>
                        </fieldset>
                        <div id="demJ">
                            <fieldset class="ui-grid-c" style="width:450px;">
                                <div class="ui-block-a labels" style="width:50px;">
                                    <label for="deb" data-inline="true">Du :</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:100px;">
                                    <input type="text" name="deb" id="deb" value="" maxlength="10" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">
                                    <input type="hidden" id="altdeb" value="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="ui-block-c" style="width:40px;">
                                    <div class="ui-icon-nodisc">
                                        <a id="caldeb" data-role="button" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="b" data-iconshadow="false" data-inline="true"></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ui-block-d" style="width:200px;">
                                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" data-type="horizontal">
                                        <input type="radio" name="ajpdeb" id="ajpdeb-j" value="2" checked="checked" />
                                        <label for="ajpdeb-j">Jour</label>

                                        <input type="radio" name="ajpdeb" id="ajpdeb-a" value="1"  />
                                        <label for="ajpdeb-a">Matin</label>

                                        <input type="radio" name="ajpdeb" id="ajpdeb-p" value="3"  />
                                        <label for="ajpdeb-p">Soir</label>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ui-block-a labels" style="width:50px;">
                                    <label for="deb">Au :</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:100px;">
                                    <input type="text" name="fin" id="fin" value="" maxlength="10" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">
                                    <input type="hidden" id="altfin" value="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="ui-block-c" style="width:40px;">
                                    <div class="ui-icon-nodisc">
                                        <a id="calfin" data-role="button" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="b" data-iconshadow="false" data-inline="true"></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ui-block-d" style="width:200px;">
                                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" data-type="horizontal">
                                        <input type="radio" name="ajpfin" id="ajpfin-j" value="2" checked="checked" />
                                        <label for="ajpfin-j">Jour</label>

                                        <input type="radio" name="ajpfin" id="ajpfin-a" value="1"  />
                                        <label for="ajpfin-a">Matin</label>

                                        <input type="radio" name="ajpfin" id="ajpfin-p" value="3"  />
                                        <label for="ajpfin-p">Soir</label>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <div id="demH" style="display:none;">
                            <fieldset class="ui-grid-c" style="width:450px;">
                                <div class="ui-block-a labels" style="width:50px;">
                                    <label for="date" data-inline="true">Date :</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:100px;">
                                    <input type="text" name="date" id="date" value="" maxlength="10" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">
                                    <input type="hidden" id="altdate" value="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="ui-block-c" style="width:40px;">
                                    <div class="ui-icon-nodisc">
                                        <a id="caldate" data-role="button" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="b" data-iconshadow="false" data-inline="true"></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ui-block-d labels" style="width:100px;">
                                    <label for="hdeb" data-inline="true">Heure début :</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ui-block-e" style="width:90px;">
                                    <input type="time" name="hdeb" id="hdeb" value="" maxlength="5" placeholder="HH:MM" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">
                                </div>
                                <div class="ui-block-a labels" style="width:50px;">
                                </div>
                                <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:100px;">
                                </div>
                                <div class="ui-block-c" style="width:40px;">
                                </div>
                                <div class="ui-block-d labels" style="width:100px;">
                                    <label for="hfin" data-inline="true">Heure fin :</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ui-block-e" style="width:90px;">
                                    <input type="time" name="hfin" id="hfin" value="" maxlength="5" placeholder="HH:MM" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <fieldset class="ui-grid-b" style="width:450px;">
                            <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:100px;">
                                <a href="#" id="rechabs" data-role="button" style="width:80px" data-icon="search" data-mini="true" title="Rechercher les motifs d'absences">Motifs</a>
                            </div>
                            <div id="divmotabs" class="ui-block-b" style="width:350px;">
                            **<-- Here the SELECT is added dynamically -->**
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**JavaSCRIPT**

```
        var $tab = '<select id="motabs" data-mini="true" data-native-menu="true">';
        for (var $i in motAbs) {
            if (profil['ABS'] != undefined && profil['ABS'] != null && canDo(profil['ABS'].lst.split(';').join(','),motAbs[$i].code))
                $tab+= '<option value="'+motAbs[$i].code+'">'+motAbs[$i].code + " " + motAbs[$i].lib + " (" + motAbs[$i].val +')</option>';
        }
        $tab+= '</select>';
        $('#divmotabs').empty();
        $('#divmotabs').append($tab);
        $('#motabs').selectmenu();
```

Answer (score 0):

i know this is a pretty old post, but in case the issue is still there.

after you append "$tab"

you should write, $('#motabs').trigger('create').selectmenu();

i think that should work